# How to cancel ajax when route changing using react router

Tags: react-router, rxjs, rxjs5, react-router-redux, redux-observable

```
 export const getSomethingEpic = action$ =>
  action$
    .ofType(GET_SOMETHING)
    .switchMap(action =>
      ajax('url/api/something')
        .map((json) => {
          return getSomethingEndAct(json.response);
        })
        .takeUntil(action$.ofType('@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE'))
    );
```

The situation is this:

page A has a react router Link to page B, on page B componentDidMount I dispatch getSomething action. Ajax can be cancelled perfectly. However, if page B loaded and the ajax finished, we route to page C from page B, and then use the browser back button to route to page B again, action getSomething will be dispatched in componentDidMount again, but this time the ajax is cancelled.

I don't understand why the ajax is being cancelled since location change is prior to getSomething action.
Or what should I do to cancel ajax when route changed?

I tried to build an example, but I could not get react-router-redux to sync browser history. here is http://jsbin.com/dewixurece/edit?js,console,output 
it would be working if use hashHistory, but there will be two location change actions, which should be one instead and I don't know why.

it is a great lib and I really like RX programming idea, but still learning and hope we could have more examples. thanks if anyone can help.

Comment: It's hard to understand what the problem is? It sounds like you're saying you want it to be cancelled when you leave but you don't want it to be cancelled when you leave, which is contradictory. Can you rephrase?

Comment: Sorry, Making it clear:  I want it to be cancelled when I leave page B, but it actually cancelled if I use browser navigation button back to page B from page C. When I nav back to (entering back) page B, ajax action dispatched and cancelled, which I don't want it to be.

Comment: Hmmm hard to say without seeing a working example. I noticed you're using `switchMap` which means that if you have a pending `ajax('url/api/something')` and _another_ `GET_SOMETHING` action comes in, it will cancel the pending one and start a new one. Don't know if that's what you mean? Can you create a JSBin demoing the problem? http://jsbin.com/zomire/edit?js,output

Comment: Thanks @jayphelps  I have made an example based on yours with react-router-redux, but it isn't working properly inside jsbin. Maybe could you please give me an example of cancelling ajax when user change route. My approach is to listen if the action type is LOCATION_CHANGE which is react-router-redux's action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(based on our discussion in the comments)

If you want to start a request when you enter a route, but cancel it if you leave that route before it's finished, you would dispatch the start action in `componentDidMount` and the cancellation action in `componentWillUnmount`

```
const getSomethingEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType('GET_SOMETHING')
    .switchMap(action =>
      ajax('url/api/something')
        .map((json) => {
          return getSomethingEndAct(json.response);
        })
        .takeUntil(action$.ofType('GET_SOMETHING_CANCELLED'))
    );

class B extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    store.dispatch({
      type: 'GET_SOMETHING'
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    store.dispatch({
      type: 'GET_SOMETHING_CANCELLED'
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>B route</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/zomire/edit?js,output

For simplicity sake, I just used `store.dispatch` directly. Use action creators and/or `connect()` in your real app, if you prefer that.

Dispatching the cancellation action, even if the ajax request has already completed isn't usually a problem--but if it is or you prefer to only dispatch it if it's truly needed, you'll need to store some sort of state you can use to know whether or not the request is still pending. You can store this state either as local component state or in the redux store.